# Как правильно указать высоту div?

Tags: html, css

Как правильно задать высоту родительскому `block-1` так, чтобы он был минимум `100px`, но мог растягиваться при наличии большего в нем контента? При этом, дочерний `block-2` должен всегда иметь максимальную высоту.

В настоящем исполнении, либо дочерний не растягивается в высоту на `100px`, либо родителю указываем `height: 100px;` - дочерний растягивается, но теперь родитель у нас лишь на `100px` в высоту, и рано или поздно контент вылезает за рамки.

```css
.block-1 {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 50px 0;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.block-1 .block-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: azure;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="block-2">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Почему у вас родитель то 100рх то 200 рх минимум? Добавьте ему overflow-y:auto

Comment: @user202854 Опечатка, поправил. `overflow-y:auto` не сработал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Вариант 1** - position: absolute

```css
.block-1 {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 50px 0;
  min-height: 100px;
position: relative;
}

.block-2 {
  background: azure;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="block-2">test</div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 2** - display: flex

```css
.block-1 {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 50px 0;
  min-height: 100px;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: azure;
flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="block-2">test</div>
</div>
```

**Вариант 3** - display: table

```css
.block-1 {
  background: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 50px 0;
  min-height: 100px;
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

.block-2 {
  height: 100%;
  background: azure;
display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="block-2">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как более разумно использовать на Ваш взгляд? Я склоняют к варианту 2.

Comment: Все зависит от дальнейшего использования блока, и ваших привычек. Если хорошо понимаете флексбоксы, то конечно 2ой.